Nutter: how to get number of tests passed and failed
I am implementing many unit tests in the same fixture function using Nutter.
After running the command to execute the tests, it outputs the passed tests and the details of the failed ones.
result = myFixture().execute_tests()
the output is simply
============================================================
PASSING TESTS
------------------------------------------------------------
test_1 (0.2628212119998352 seconds)
test_2 (3.5343320289994153 seconds)
test_3 (0.2465618969999923 seconds)

I wonder if there is a way to display the result in a pytest fashion, for example:


result = myFixture().execute_tests(formatter="pytest")

To display the number of tests passed and failed in Nutter, you can modify the execute_tests() method to include the --verbose flag. This will display the number of tests passed and failed in the output. Here's an example:
result = myFixture().execute_tests("--verbose")
